# How to read the content of a server response after login ? (HTTP related)

Tags: http, post, winsock, content-length

my goal is to login to a vBulletin forum using C++/Winsock. The forum is forums.randi.org

For this purpose I've been sniffing the packets and here is the header of the server response to the POST request which supplies the login details:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Tue, 19 Feb 2013 18:12:52 GMT
Server  Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.8
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.8
Set-Cookie  bblastvisit=1361297572; expires=Wed, 19-Feb-2014 18:12:52 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie  bblastactivity=0; expires=Wed, 19-Feb-2014 18:12:52 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie  bbwelcomeheaders=1361297572; path=/
Set-Cookie  bbsessionhash=9ad9da23b1399e81772437c3819a2501; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control   private
Pragma  private
X-UA-Compatible IE=7
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  2152
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

My problem is that I have been trying to read the content of the response to no avail. As the header indicates, the length of the content should be 2152 bytes. I read indeed 2152 bytes into some buffer but they are gibberish (while the response header appears perfectly fine). At the same time, my sniffer (HttpFox, a Firefox plugin) shows a perfectly legitimate content, but whose size is much larger than the indicated 2152 bytes (it's about 5900 bytes).

The content, as retrieved by the sniffer after a successful login, follows. I wonder how I can read this content with winsock and why is this much longer than the Content-Length indicated in the header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: STANDARD_REDIRECT -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Tapatalk Detect Start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var tapatalk_iphone_msg = "This forum has an app for iPhone and iPod Touch! Click OK to learn more about Tapatalk.";
var tapatalk_iphone_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tapatalk-forum-app/id307880732?mt=8";
var tapatalk_ipad_msg = "This forum has an app for iPad! Click OK to learn more about Tapatalk.";
var tapatalk_ipad_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tapatalk-hd-for-ipad/id481579541?mt=8";
var tapatalk_kindle_msg = "This forum has an app for Kindle Fire! Click OK to learn more about Tapatalk.";
var tapatalk_kindle_url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.quoord.tapatalkpro.activity";
var tapatalk_android_msg = "This forum has an app for Android. Click OK to learn more about Tapatalk.";
var tapatalk_android_url = "market://details?id=com.quoord.tapatalkpro.activity";
var tapatalk_chrome_enable = true;
var tapatalkdir = "mobiquo";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forums.randi.org/mobiquo/tapatalkdetect.js"></script>
<!-- Tapatalk Detect End -->

<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE: headinclude -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 3.7.7" />

<meta name="keywords" content="randi, amazing, jref, skeptic, pigasus, debunk, critical thinking, lecture, geller, dowsing, cold reading, cottingley, weird things, paranormal, million dollar challenge, magic, faith healer, nostradamus, fraud, hoax, occult, supernatural, conjuring, uri geller, yuri, flim flam, psychics, john edward, sylvia browne, clock, van praagh,vbulletin,forum,bbs,discussion,jelsoft,bulletin board, psi, amazing meeting" />
<meta name="description" content="The JREF Forum is provided by the James Randi Educational Foundation, a non-profit educational organisation whose goals include promoting critical thinking everywhere, go to http://forums.randi.org/." />


<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css" id="vbulletin_css">
/**
* vBulletin 3.7.7 CSS
* Style: 'JREF'; Style ID: 23
*/
@import url("clientscript/vbulletin_css/style-f5050f4f-00023.css");
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_important.css?v=377" />


<!-- / CSS Stylesheet -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js?v=377"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/connection/connection-min.js?v=377"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var SESSIONURL = "";
var SECURITYTOKEN = "guest";
var IMGDIR_MISC = "http://forums.randi.org/helloworld2/misc";
var vb_disable_ajax = parseInt("0", 10);
// -->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_global.js?v=377"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_menu.js?v=377"></script>


    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="JREF Forum RSS Feed" href="external.php?type=RSS2" />





<!-- END TEMPLATE: headinclude -->
<title>JREF Forum</title>
</head>
<body>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<form action="http://forums.randi.org/forumindex.php" method="post" name="postvarform">
<div style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
<table class="tcat-rounded" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="10" class="tcat-rounded-left"><img src="http://forums.randi.org/helloworld2/misc/spacer.gif" width="10" height="28" border="0" alt="" /></td>

    <td class="tcat">Redirecting...</td>
        <td width="10" class="tcat-rounded-right"><img src="http://forums.randi.org/helloworld2/misc/spacer.gif" width="10" height="28" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="70%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="panelsurround" align="center">
    <div class="panel">

        <blockquote>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><strong>Thank you for logging in, XXXX.</strong></p>

                <p class="smallfont"><a href="http://forums.randi.org/forumindex.php">Click here if your browser does not automatically redirect you.</a></p>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>

        </blockquote>

    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>



<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; URL=http://forums.randi.org/forumindex.php" />
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function exec_refresh()
{
    window.status = "Redirecting..." + myvar;
    myvar = myvar + " .";
    var timerID = setTimeout("exec_refresh();", 100);
    if (timeout > 0)
    {
        timeout -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        window.status = "";
        window.location = "http://forums.randi.org/forumindex.php";
    }
}

var myvar = "";
var timeout = 20;
exec_refresh();
//-->
</script>



</body>
</html>
<!-- END TEMPLATE: STANDARD_REDIRECT -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `2152` bytes are reffered to the `gzipped data` sent (look at the `Content-Encoding    gzip` header) while `HttpFox` show you the data already un-gzipped.